# Can't modify the value of the session within event handlers for websockets events

Tags: python, websocket, flask, redis, socket.io

I'm building a little flask&pyhon-based app and my main feature is based on websockets. I discovered that I can't modify the value of the sesssion within event handlers for websockets events(I'm using `flask-socketio`) because flask stores its session on the client side. So, as the author of the extension recomanded I installed `flask-kvsession` to store the session on the server-side in a `redis`-based backend.

I followed the instructions presented http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-KVSession/, but the problem persists. So I created a little program to show you what I'm talking about.

```
# main.py
from flask import Flask, session, render_template
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO
from pprint import pprint
import redis
from flask_kvsession import KVSessionExtension
from simplekv.memory.redisstore import RedisStore

store = RedisStore(redis.StrictRedis())

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.secret_key = 'secret!'
KVSessionExtension(store, app)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    pprint(session)
    return render_template("client.html")

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect(message):
    session['debug'] = 'debug'

    pprint(session)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app)


<!-- templates/client.html  -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/
            socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var sock = io.connect('http:localhost:5000');
            sock.emit('connect', {debug: 'debug'});
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Here is the output of the werkzeug debuging server:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
<KVSession {}>
127.0.0.1 - - [2014-07-04 21:25:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 442 0.004452
<KVSession {'debug': 'debug'}>
<KVSession {}>
127.0.0.1 - - [2014-07-04 21:26:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 442 0.000923
<KVSession {'debug': 'debug'}>
```

I'd expect that the second time when I will access that page the contents of the session to be `'debug': 'debug'` but it is not.

Here is what happened on the redis server while I was running this app:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> MONITOR
OK
1404498351.888321 [0 127.0.0.1:38129] "GET" "136931c509f674e3_53b6e25b"
1404498352.073011 [0 127.0.0.1:38129] "GET" "136931c509f674e3_53b6e25b"
1404498362.455320 [0 127.0.0.1:38129] "GET" "136931c509f674e3_53b6e25b"
1404498362.612346 [0 127.0.0.1:38129] "GET" "136931c509f674e3_53b6e25b"
```

As you can see, the value of the session is accessed 4 times, but is never modfied. 
So, what should I do to fix this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the documentation, Flask-SocketIO does not write sessions back to the session store, it just keeps them in memory and accessible to socket handlers.

If you want changes to the server-side session to persist and be available to regular HTTP clients you have to save the session yourself after you make those changes. I haven't tested this myself, but I think this will do:

```
session.modified = True
app.save_session(session, make_response('dummy'))
```

Note that `save_session()` gets a dummy response. This will only work if the session was already established in a regular HTTP call before this. Obviously a new session will not be created with the code above, since the response will be discarded and never reach the client.